# What is invokescript tag?

Tags: support

What is [invokescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invokescript) tag supposed to represent? When you click on it in the description area it reads "The invokescript tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?"

Is this a useful tag? If yes, what is it for?

Comment: It is the name of a method that activates javascript in a hosted browser.   Useful is a big word, it is not un-useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32 questions tagged [invokescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invokescript) seem to be about the .NET [HtmlDocument.InvokeScript method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz(v=vs.110).aspx). Since there are relatively few questions about it on Stack Overflow, it appears nobody has written a tag description for it yet.